# Autoloader unable to load the dependency

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I see that my dependency use

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"Ion\\": "src/"}
}
```

And at the src/container folder

```
<?php
namespace Ion;

class Container
```

And, I try to load it using the autoloader (of course I've `composer require` that library)

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Ion\Container;

$ion = new Container();
```

But, it turns out to be a fatal error
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Ion\Container' not found in C:\UniServerZ\www\projects\playground\ion\test.php on line 6`

What's wrong with this? Anyway to fix it?
Please help

This is the package (which I code) : https://packagist.org/packages/terrydjony/ion

Comment: composer require will install your package in /vendor/ folder.
make sure your package is installed in that folder.
you might not need add that autoload statement in composer.json.

Comment: if you have something new in autoload file then try following command. php -dump autoload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded your package and troubleshoot the issue. Actually, you need to place your file in a folder called `Ion`. It should be `src/Ion/Container.php` instead of `ion/src/Container.php`.

```
+-- src
|   +-- Ion
|       +-- Container.php
+-- vendor
+-- composer.json
```

Another small mistake you made, your class filename is in lowercase `container.php` but you defined it in uppercase.

```
class Container
{

}
```

Comment: What if I just want to let the file in `src/Container.php` ?  Can I do ` "psr-4": {"": "src/"} `